# Consumir una api con Bearer Token

Tags: python, api, python-requests

Tengo que consumir una api, que esta protegida con un Bearer Token, y necesito poder hacer un get, para obtener cierta data.

```
url = "" #La url de la api ya contiene la información a requisar
access_token = "" #Aqui pongo el Bearer Token que ya tengo generado previamente
headers =  {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}

result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(result.status_code)
```

Esto me da un error 403.
¿Alguien sabe como pasar correctamente el Bearer Token

Comment: Tu código se ve bien. Parece un problema específico de la API. Sólo para estar seguros, el access token que estás usando no expiro, verdad?

Comment: Gracias por responder!, pues acabo de generar otro token y sigue dando lo mismo.
Me falto añadir que en Postman funciona perfectamente la petición, solo que no lo logro replicar en python

Comment: ahora se puso más interesante entonces. La respuesta de la API, aparte del status 403 no te da algo más de información, osea en el body de la respuesta? Y estás 100% seguro de que no te falta ningún otro parámetro?

Comment: Por cierto Postman te permite convertir una petición a código. En la columna de más a la derecha hay un botón `</>`. Solo selecciona `Python - Requests` y listo.

Comment: Gracias!, no me sabia ese truco del Postman, resulta que tenia que usar http.client para poder acceder, Muchas gracias!

Comment: Revisa que otro detalle estas omitiendo de la API, porque la forma como lo estas haciendo es correcta para consumir una API con Bearer Token.